# How to create schedule between players

Tags: java, algorithm

I have map of groups. Each groups have list of players:

```
Map<String, List<Player>> playerByGroup = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Player>>();
```

for example:

map contains:

```
 group A: players 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 group B: players 7 8 9 10 11 12 
 group C: players 13 14 15 16 17 18 
 group D: players 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

now I need to create schedule. Each player from every groups should be player with player from another group

for example:

player 1 should be player with player 7 - 24 but not with player 2 - 6

this isnt problem to create

But now I have problem:

I need to create round which contains numberOfPlayer/2 of games. In round every player can play just once

for example

```
1.round should be looks like:

1.game 1 vs 7
2.game 13 vs 19
3.game 3 vs 9
4.game 14 vs 20
5.game 2 vs 8
6.game 15 vs 21
7.game 4 vs 10
8.game 16 vs 22
9.game 5 vs 11
10.game 17 vs 23
11.game 6 vs 12
12.game 18 vs 24

2.round ...
```

there should be just 18 rounds because one player should play with 18 players.

PROBLEM:

Problem is to create just 18 rounds where in each round one player play just once

Comment: If I understand it right, each player should play with all players from another teams just once. am I correct?

Comment: +1 for admitting this is homework! However, you need to show us what you've tried so far. We appreciate you don't yet know the answer (otherwise you wouldn't be here), but equally we expect you've had a go at solving it yourself before you posted.

Comment: I just create schedule for 24 player in 4 groups (manually) and now I am looking for some algorithm how it works

Comment: Surely if you've done this manually you used an algorithm ?  You might not have realised it at the time but you surely did.  Now all you have to do is translate it into code.

Comment: nope I just created it with method trial and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the answer for you example. <strike>it's easy to extend it for general situations.</strike>

divide your rounds into three main set so we have 6 round in each set.

in the first set with six rounds:

all players of group A will play to all players of group B and all players of group C will play to all players of group D.

in the second set all players of group A will play to all players of group C and all players of group B will play to all players of group D.
in the third set all players of group A will play to all players of group D and all players of group B will play to all players of group C.

Comment: version that work with 2n+1 : half players from A play with half player from B, other half player from B play with half player from C ... you'll notice that it requires an even number of players or teams (which makes sense, try with 3 teams of 1)

Comment: I have updated my answer. but if your groups have even number of person, njzk2 sollution is correct and can help you when you have odd number of groups. if both the number of person in each group and the number of groups is odd, it's not possible to have a complete round because we have odd number of person in total.

Answer (score 0):

Hint to you :

Think of it as an combinations problem you have `6` people in each group. Number of groups `4`. you need each player to play but not with in group, then total number of combinations would be
`24C4 - 4*(6*(6-1)/2)` ( `C` is [Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))or 
`(24*23*22*21)(4*3*2*1) - 4*(6*(6-1)/2)`. Code accordingly.

Comment: where did you get 5 groups ? And what operations is 24C5 ?

Comment: @hudi C is combination I have provided a Wiki link to it, you can read further or use other approach.

Comment: hm ok but if I am right this is just count of game what as I said isnt problem to create. Problem is to create round where one player play just once